# Charset of attachment file name

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmailer

Good Day,

I'm sending an email with an attachement via SMTP with PHPMailer.

The charset in the mail is set to utf-8, but when I send an attachement with an special char like 'März' for example, the client gets an attachement with an broken charset like: M�rz.

My Code Example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host = "host ip";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "user";
$mail->Password = "pw";

$mail->setFrom('send@host.de', 'Host');
$mail->addAddress("client@mail.de");
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body = "Email Content";
$mail->AltBody = 'Alternative Email Content';

$mail->AddAttachment("example/file_märz.pdf");
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: Is the problem with the file name or the content of the PDF?

Comment: Its the filename of the PDF, the pdf itself is fine

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PHPMailer in the attachment process i found `basename`
was used.  So to correctly output the specific encoding you need to `setlocale` depending on what charset compatible to your filename.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');
```

the above code worked for me. Since I am using Japanese language/text for my filename.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the filename, and you're writing the file name inside the source code of your application (in the PHP file), then the problem can be one or both of the following:

1. The PHP file is saved with the wrong encoding. That is, you're telling PHPMailer to send UTF-8 emails, but your PHP file could be saved in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Thus, when PHP reads the `"example/file_märz.pdf"`, it reads the byte sequence in ISO-8859-1, but then it tells PHPMailer to interpret it as UTF-8.
   Solution: ensure your text editor is saving files in UTF-8
2. The operating system and/or client does not support Unicode file names for attachment.
   Solution: there isn't really a solution, you need to avoid non-ASCII characters in file names (which couldn't be a bad idea anyways).

If your editor is already set to UTF-8 and you are sure your client/OS support Unicode in filenames, you need to check the raw email that PHPMailer sends and see what it contains. Many email clients let you see the raw email (the entire raw text).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ensured, that the .php file is saved in UTF-8, that was the case. Also the file is running on an Debian Linux Server 7, that is capable of unicode file names. When I look up the attachement file, it is encoded and shown correctly. When I look up the raw headers of the mail I get an '=C3=A4' (what seems to be the correct utf-8 character) in the attachement name instead of the 'ä', is that any help maybe?

Comment: Yes that is correct, and it's how it should be. Then it's my #2, but not on the server rather on the client. Possibly your email client (or client OS) doesn't support Unicode filenames.

Comment: Hm strange, we use Windows 7 PCs with Microsoft Outlook 2010 mail clients. But you're right, the mail itself seems to be correct.

Comment: Found something interesting maybe. I mistaked the attachement name with the mail subject (attachement header was not shown in Outlook, sry..), so the correct '=C3=A4' was in the subject. In the attachement, the 'ä' is shown as '=E4', what seems to be the unicode position. Gmail interprets it correct, but Outlook not. Any ideas for this maybe?

Comment: You're correct. E4 is the Unicode codepoint, while the correct byte sequence would be C3+A4 (source: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ ). E4 is also the byte sequence in ISO-8859-1, however: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm and this makes me think that it could totally be, again, my point #1 above.

Comment: PHPMailer, on its end, is doing the encoding: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v5.2.9/class.phpmailer.php#L2183 I really believe your PHP files aren't saved properly, sincerely. I can't find any other explanation

Answer (score -2):

> Blockquote

I had the same problem.

It can be solve by adding:

utf8_encode() function to the $name of the attachment[] array.

On my version of phpmailer is located on class.phpmailer.php on line 1322.